# Taking long time from controller to service layer in springboot using transactional at service method

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard, transactional

I have a spring boot application and was load testing using ab for 100 concurrent request (ab -c 100 -n 100 ... ).
Resource/Controller layer simply calls the service layer 
which has following code:

```
@Override
@Transactional()
public void test(Long resourceLayerTime){
    log.info("time taken to reach service --------- "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using spring transactional here. What I found was that for many of the requests, time taken to reach service layer is of order 2s, 4s, 6s...12s. Making total testing time of all request ~23s.
Without transactional, everything is fine and total request timing ~2s.

Same thing when tested on dropwizard application using guice transactional had total timings of ~2s (as expected because of sleep of 2s).

Can anyone please explain what can be the issue here?

Comment: have set connection pool size to 100, and using mysql database

Comment: using Hikari for connection pooling